# Check how much money there is in my Bitcoin address/wallet

Tags: wallet, address

Is there a website or service that can quickly lookup how much bitcoins are there in a given wallet/address, so I can look up my own wallet from a friend's computer which doesn't have the Bitcoin client installed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info).

Just paste the address you want to check into the Search inputbox and the website will show you all the transactions where that address was involved, as well as the balance.

Comment: Note: Blockchain.info only works for single addresses. You cannot search multiple addresses of a wallet at once

Answer (score 3):

In [Blockonomics](https://www.blockonomics.co) you can search multiple addresses of a wallet at once. It also has a [wallet watcher](https://www.blockonomics/blockonomics)  where you can enter multiple addresses  and get the overall balance in btc and currency of your choice. You can also see history of tx

Comment: Blockchain.info has been slow and buggy for me today, and so have the other alternatives I tried until coming across your answer. I like how fast Blockonomics showed me my balance even though it's still "uncomfirmed". That's a good feature.